# Java based OpenCV in Android : Want to overlap an image onto another image only where the mask has non-zero values

Tags: java, android, opencv

I know that my question is a rather basic question, but I tried several days to solve this problem, and can't find the exact answer to my question on Stackoverflow too.

I have a background image, and I want to overlap the foreground image onto it, but only on the regions where my mask has non-zero
values. The code that I wrote is as below. The foreground image appears in 
the regions where the mask has non-zero values (in the upper left quarter of the
whole image region), but in the rest of the image, the background does not appear, it just appears 'black'.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help
with this problem. A similar code works well for OpenCV for C language.

The background image (background.bmp) and the foreground image (foreground.bmp),
are being read in without problem (this I have verified).

---

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String pathToBackground  
            = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/background.bmp";
String pathToForeground  
            = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foreground.bmp";

Mat foreground;   
Mat background;  
background = imread(pathToBackground);  // read in the background image
foreground = imread(pathToForeground); // read in the foreground image

Bitmap back_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/background.bmp"); 
Utils.bitmapToMat(back_bitmap, background);  // convert from bitmap to Mat

 Mat mask2 = 
 new Mat( new Size(foreground.cols(), foreground.rows() ), CvType.CV_8UC1);
 mask2.setTo( new Scalar( 0 ) );    // set the mask to all zero

 Size sizeMask = mask2.size();

    for (int i=0;i<sizeMask.height/2;i++ )  // making the upper left quarter 
        for (int j=0;j<sizeMask.width/2;j++ )  //of the whole mask image                                                
            mask2.put(i, j, 10);              // non-zero

   foreground.copyTo(background, mask2); // copy the foreground image on to 
                                         // the background image where the
                                         // mask2 has non-zero value
                                         // --> not working as expected

   Utils.matToBitmap(background, back_bitmap);  // convert from Mat to Bitmap
   ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   v.setImageBitmap(back_bitmap); // only the foreground image appears in the
                                  // upper left region. The remaining region
                                  // is just black.
                                  // The remaining region should show the
                                  // background image.
```

Comment: I am almost certain, that using `PorterDuff.Mode` class will make it easier.

Comment: Can you attach sample inputs and outputs ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I'm now googling for PorterDuff.Mode.
The reason I use Java OpenCV is that in the future I want to extend the code to overlap an image onto the frame image obtained by the phone camera.
But anyway, I think I have to consider PorterDuff.Mode too.

Comment: I will soon attach the input and the output image.

Comment: I would make an empty mat, the size of the original image and then put values depending on what you want. Then you can change the mat to bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments of 'Rick M.', I could solve the problem by the following code (though not very neat). I made an empty bitmap('back_bitmap') instead of
putting an initial image in it. The result is as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgukt.jpg).
Before I could not see the background image.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String pathToBackground  = 
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/background.bmp";
    String pathToForeground  = 
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foreground.bmp";

    Mat foreground;
    Mat background;
    background = imread(pathToBackground);
    foreground = imread(pathToForeground);

    Bitmap back_bitmap 
    = Bitmap.createBitmap(foreground.cols(), foreground.rows(), 
      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  // Make an empty Bitmap

   Mat mask2 
   = new Mat( new Size( foreground.cols(), foreground.rows() ), 
                   CvType.CV_8UC1 );
    mask2.setTo( new Scalar( 0 ) );

    Size sizeMask = mask2.size();
    double[] data;
       for (int i=0;i<sizeMask.height;i++ )
         for (int j=0;j<sizeMask.width;j++ ) {
             data = foreground.get(i, j);
             if (data[0] + data[1] + data[2] > 0)
                 mask2.put(i, j, 10);
         }
    foreground.copyTo(background, mask2);
    Utils.matToBitmap(background, back_bitmap);
    ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    v.setImageBitmap(back_bitmap);
    }
   }
```